# creating n amount of threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java method, where I want to create n amount of threads, and then make each thread print out the numbers from 1 to 100.

```
public void createThreads(int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                System.out.println(j);


            }
        });       
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this method, nothing is printed out, even when I pass a parameter. How can I fix this?

Comment: Just start the threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is printed because you are not starting the threads.

```
public void createThreads(int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
                System.out.println(j);
            }
        }).start(); // <-- .start() makes the thread start running   
    }
}
```

Also note that I've changed your for loop to `for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++)`, because the intention is to print numbers from `1` to `100` (an not from `0` to `99`).

Answer (score 3):

Creating threads isn't enough, you need to [start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) them as well.

```
new Thread(() -> { ... }).start();
```

---

*I would recommend a bit of refactoring here.*

From a method with the name `createThreads` I expect the created threads to be returned - `Thread[] createThreads(int n)` (1).

The code isn't easily readable - moving a `Thread`'s `Runnable` into a separate method would make it clearer (2).

The name `createThreads` becomes inaccurate if you both create and start threads (3) within the method. Either rename it to `createAndStartThreads` or create two separate methods `createThreads` and `startThreads` which is more preferable since [a method should take a single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

```
public Thread[] createThreads(int n) {
    final Thread[] threads = new Thread[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        threads[i] = new Thread(this::doTask);
    }

    return threads;
}

private void doTask() {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}

public void startThreads(Thread[] threads) {
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done to create N number of threads.
 Here mentioning quite different approach if you want to specify name of your 
 thread.

```
1. Thread T[] = new Thread[list.size()];
2. for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
3.     T[i] = new Thread(new constructor_name());
4.     T[i].setName(list.get(i));
5.     T[i].start();
6. }
```

Explanation:

1. Create array of threads with your list size.
2. Execute loop till last element of the list.
3. Within loop Initiate, Assign and Start the thread.

Execution of threads:

```
public void run() {        
    try {
         method_name(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

Note: Here method_name(thread_parameter) is invoked synchronously for every element of list.